# In a Tkinter Treeview, how to sort descending in relation to a specific column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

How can I sort the `Badge` column numbers in descending order (9, 7, 5, 4, 3, 1)? Naturally, by ordering the `Badge` numbers, the order of the lines will also change. I would like to get:

```
5,"Frank","9"
3,"Daniel","7"
4,"Leonard","5"
1,"Jack","4"
6,"Robert","3"
2,"Tom","1"
```

I found some examples on the web, but I couldn't apply them to my code. Can you show me the solution using my code please?

Code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

ws = Tk()
ws.title('PythonGuides')
ws.geometry('400x300')
ws['bg']='#fb0'

data  = [
    [1,"Jack","4"],
    [2,"Tom","1"],
    [3,"Daniel","7"],
    [4,"Leonard","5"],
    [5,"Frank","9"],
    [6,"Robert","3"],
    ]

tv = ttk.Treeview(ws)
tv['columns']=('Rank', 'Name', 'Badge')
tv.column('#0', width=0, stretch=NO)
tv.column('Rank', anchor=CENTER, width=80)
tv.column('Name', anchor=CENTER, width=80)
tv.column('Badge', anchor=CENTER, width=80)
tv.heading('#0', text='', anchor=CENTER)
tv.heading('Rank', text='Id', anchor=CENTER)
tv.heading('Name', text='rank', anchor=CENTER)
tv.heading('Badge', text='Badge', anchor=CENTER)
tv.pack()


def func1():
    for record in data:
        Rank = record[0]
        Name = record[1]
        Badge = record[2]
        
        datagrid = [Rank, Name, Badge]

        tv.insert(parent='', index='end', values=(datagrid))

button = Button(ws, text="Button", command = func1)
button.place(x=1, y=1)

ws.mainloop()
```

Comment: "I found some examples on the web, but I couldn't apply them to my code. Can you show me the solution using my code please?" - this is not answerable, because we don't know what examples you found, how you tried to apply them, what went wrong, or what you didn't understand about them. Please keep in mind that this is **not a discussion forum or help desk**; questions here **are not** about helping you personally solve a coding issue, but about... asking and answering questions, in a way that helps to build a searchable Q&A library, as described in the [tour].

Answer (score 0):

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

ws = Tk()
ws.title('PythonGuides')
ws.geometry('400x300')
ws['bg']='#fb0'

data  = [
    [1,"Jack","4"],
    [2,"Tom","1"],
    [3,"Daniel","7"],
    [4,"Leonard","5"],
    [5,"Frank","9"],
    [6,"Robert","3"],
    ]

tv = ttk.Treeview(ws)
tv['columns']=('Rank', 'Name', 'Badge')
tv.column('#0', width=0, stretch=NO)
tv.column('Rank', anchor=CENTER, width=80)
tv.column('Name', anchor=CENTER, width=80)
tv.column('Badge', anchor=CENTER, width=80)
tv.heading('#0', text='', anchor=CENTER)
tv.heading('Rank', text='Id', anchor=CENTER)
tv.heading('Name', text='rank', anchor=CENTER)
tv.heading('Badge', text='Badge', anchor=CENTER, command=lambda: sort_treeview(tv, "Badge", False))
tv.pack()
def sort_treeview(tv, col, descending):
    

    data = [(tv.set(item, col), item) for item in tv.get_children('')]
    data.sort(reverse=descending)
    
    for index, item in enumerate(data):
        tv.move(item[1], '', index)
        print(item)
    tv.heading(col, command=lambda: sort_treeview(tv, col, not descending))

def func1():
    for record in data:
        Rank = record[0]
        Name = record[1]
        Badge = record[2]
        
        datagrid = [Rank, Name, Badge]

        tv.insert(parent='', index='end', values=(datagrid))

button = Button(ws, text="Button", command = func1)
button.place(x=1, y=1)

ws.mainloop()
```